# Manually invoking Windows' "Network Connections"

Tags: windows, windows-xp

In Windows XP the "Network Connections" window can be opened by executing *ncpa.cpl*. However, Windows internally seems to invoke *%WINDIR%\system32\netshell.dll,-1200*. Is there any way to manually access it through this DLL? I tried launching it via RUNDLL32 but alas.

This is just a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reference to a string resource: string resource 1200 in that DLL is "Network Connections".